# Facebook.authorizeCallback results with a NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

I'v been trying to use Facebook SDK in my app, but suddenly the app started crashing when calling `Facebook.authorizeCallback` with this Logcat crash report:

```
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32665, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.thepoosh/com.thepoosh.CoveActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.thepoosh.myActivity$1.onComplete(CoveActivity.java:124)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorizeCallback(Facebook.java:433)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.thepoosh.myActivity.onActivityResult(CoveActivity.java:191)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-19 13:28:24.335: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     ... 11 more
```

this is my code for this:

```
public final String[] PERMISSIONS = {};
private final String APPID = "239304262850291";
public final Facebook FACEBOOK = new Facebook(APPID);
private void loginAndAuthorize() {
FACEBOOK.authorize(CoveActivity.this,PERMISSIONS,
            new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Facebook error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                            "there was an error connecting to Facebook",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "General error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                            "there was an error connecting to Facebook",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    isLogged = true;
                    /* DO STUFF WITH INFORMATION */

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook login Cancelled");
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Login Cancelled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    FACEBOOK.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

any thoughts on how to fix this? (it used to work until 5 minutes ago...)

Comment: What is on line 124 of your Activity? That's where the crash is.

Comment: did u resolved this issue?

Comment: yes, the hashkey was not valid. since then, the new SDK came out and made things easier...